# Assembly X86 add to structure

Tags: assembly, x86, structure

If I need to remember some words and a code allocated for each of these words, is it possible to put them in a structure?

```
List struct
word_string db 20 dup(0)
code1 db 0
List ends

       ...

push offset wd1       ---reading the first word
push offset format
push pointer_file1
call fscanf

push offset code     ---reading the first code
push offset format
push pointer_file1
call fscanf
```

Which syntax allows me to add wd1 to word_string and code to code1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters for fscanf are `FILE* file, const char* format_string, ...` where "..." are basically pointers of particular variables for particular type specifiers in the format string.

The structure is not allocating any memory, only defining abstract "structure" of data.

So you should have shown where your structure resides (I particularly don't like when some ASM programmer doesn't treat data ahead of code, because data are a bit more important in Assembly, yet you show more of your code than of your data... that will very likely get you into problems over time which would be a bit easier to avoid when you treat your data mentally as first-class citizen, and code only as next to it), considering *"words"* usage you will probably have several of them, let's say a fixed array for simplicity, in .DATA section:

```
tenLists List 10 DUP (<>)

; and formatting string to read data like "oneWord 123"
list_scanf_format DB "%19s %hhu",0
```

Now to access n-th List you can do for example this (this will read 5th List from the fixed array):

```
mov  eax,4   ; "input" index of 5th list in array

; calculate addresses of struct/fields when index is known
imul eax,SIZEOF List  ; eax = offset of 5th struct in array
add  eax,OFFSET tenLists  ; eax = absolute address of tenLists[4]

lea  ebx,(List PTR [eax]).code1
push ebx     ; pointer to tenLists[4].code1

lea  ebx,(List PTR [eax]).word_string
push ebx     ; pointer to tenLists[4].word_string

push OFFSET list_scanf_format
push pointer_file1
call fscanf
```

If you would do this for example in some kind of loop, like reading ten lists, then you can do:

```
    mov ebx,OFFSET tenLists   ; absolute address of tenLists[0]
    mov ecx,10
readLoop:
    push ecx     ; preserve ecx from fscanf

    lea  eax,(List PTR [ebx]).code1
    push eax     ; pointer to tenLists[i].code1

    lea  eax,(List PTR [ebx]).word_string
    push eax     ; pointer to tenLists[i].word_string

    push OFFSET list_scanf_format
    push pointer_file1
    call fscanf  ; does preserve ebx, if IIRC ABI correctly

    add  esp,16  ; remove arguments from stack
    pop  ecx     ; restore loop counter
    ; validate fscanf did match 2 items
    cmp  eax,2
    jne  inputDataNotFormattedWellOrEOF
    ; advance to next array element and loop
    add  ebx,SIZEOF List ; advance to next tenLists[i]
    dec  ecx
    jnz  readLoop
```

I don't have MASM to verify my syntax (or even to debug my code), so it may needs some patching to be compilable and maybe even some bug did slip in... But I hope you will get the idea and work it out.